# Is $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(G\cup H), P) \subset L^2(\Omega, G, P)+ L^2(\Omega,H, P)$ if $G$ and $H$ are two sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathscr{F}$.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

I am studying Adam Bobrowski's Functional Analysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes, and one of the proof of a theorem in the book (theorem 3.3.1, part j ) seems to implicitly using this "fact", which I am suspecting that it is not correct.

Moreover, $G$ and $H$ are assumed to be independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly not true as written.  Let $\Omega$ be a sample space for two fair dice rolls, and let $G,H$ be the $\sigma$-fields generated by the first and second dice respectively.  Then the left side is a 36-dimensional space, while the right side is the sum of two 6-dimensional spaces.